# Sbt higher than 1.3.0 still goes to /home/ivy2/local for resolver reference instead of Coursier

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

hi I have a project which suddenly has some error when I am doing sbt load command. As my local sbt is 1.3.2, the project specified sbt version is 1.5.0, all of them are bigger than 1.3.0, this sbt project should go to Coursier cache, but instead it goes to home_dir/.ivy2 to search for all jars. My other sbt project with same config are working just fine...

I tried delete the project and refork one, invalidate the Intellij cache, use jvm8 and jvm11, add vm parameters to Intellij sbt build tools:

```
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
-Dsbt.coursier.home=/Users/userId/Library/Caches/Coursier
```

None of them works...

This is my project setting:

sbt version from cmd: 1.3.2,
build.properties specify `sbt.version=1.5.0`,
scala version in build.sbt is `2.12.15`,
Intellij IDEA  2022.3.3 (Community Edition),
sbt plugin is 2022.3.20

Here are the log details when I trigger sbt load:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.installation.dir=/Users/userName/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/223.8836.41/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents -jar /Users/userName/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/223.8836.41/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app.plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar   
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.0 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 11.0.13)   
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from credentials.sbt,plugins.sbt ...   
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/userName/.sbt/1.0/plugins   
[info] loading settings for project bladelier-tools-build from plugins.sbt ...   
[info] loading project definition from /Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/project   
[info] loading settings for project bladelierTools from build.sbt,release.sbt ...   
[info] resolving key references (13788 settings) ...   
GitDescribeOutput(GitRef(v3.1.8),GitCommitSuffix(1,78230b7a),GitDirtySuffix(+20230712-1013))   
[info] set current project to bladelier-tools (in build file:/Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/)   
[warn] there are 3 keys that are not used by any other settings/tasks:   
[warn]   
[warn] * common / maintainer   
[warn]   +- /Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/build.sbt:181   
[warn] * bladelierTools / Test / coverageEnabled   
[warn]   +- /Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/build.sbt:7   
[warn] * bladelierTools / gitRemoteRepo   
[warn]   +- /Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/build.sbt:47   
[warn]   
[warn] note: a setting might still be used by a command; to exclude a key from this `lintUnused` check   
[warn] either append it to `Global / excludeLintKeys` or call .withRank(KeyRanks.Invisible) on the key   
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/userName/.sbt/1.0/server/c5dd0c64a5baeb389dda/sock   
[info] started sbt server   
sbt:bladelier-tools>   
;set _root_.scala.collection.Seq(historyPath := None,shellPrompt := { _ => "" }   
,SettingKey[_root_.scala.Option[_root_.sbt.File]]("sbtStructureOutputFile")   
in _root_.sbt.Global := _root_.scala.Some(_root_.sbt.file("/private/var/folders/v9/vbxmj8w54bn_9s_258z0z34c0000gq/T/sbt-structure.xml")),SettingKey[_root_.java.lang.String]   
("sbtStructureOptions")   
in _root_.sbt.Global := "download, resolveClassifiers")   
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile and 1 others.   
[info] The new values will be used by cleanKeepGlobs   
[info]  Run `last` for details.   
[info] Reapplying settings...   
GitDescribeOutput(GitRef(v3.1.8),GitCommitSuffix(1,78230b7a),GitDirtySuffix(+20230712-1013))   
[info] set current project to bladelier-tools (in build file:/Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/)   
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/userName/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/223.8836.41/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app.plugins/Scala/repo/org/jetbrains/scala/sbt-structure-extractor_2.12_1.0/2022.3.1/sbt-structure-extractor-2022.3.1.jar   
[info] Reapplying settings...   
GitDescribeOutput(GitRef(v3.1.8),GitCommitSuffix(1,78230b7a),GitDirtySuffix(+20230712-1013))   
[info] set current project to bladelier-tools (in build file:/Users/userName/IdeaProjects/bladelier-tools/)   
[warn] sbt 0.13 shell syntax is deprecated; use slash syntax instead: Global / dumpStructure   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/reader-index_2.12/3.1.5/reader-index_2.12-3.1.5.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/core_2.12/3.1.5/core_2.12-3.1.5.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/standalone-indexer-common_2.12/3.1.5/standalone-indexer-common_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/core_2.12/3.1.5/core_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/standalone-indexer-common_2.12/3.1.5/standalone-indexer-common_2.12-3.1.5.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/reader-index_2.12/3.1.5/reader-index_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/standalone-indexer-common_2.12/3.1.5/standalone-indexer-common_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/core_2.12/3.1.5/core_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/reader-index_2.12/3.1.5/reader-index_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/core_2.12/3.1.5/   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/reader-index_2.12/3.1.5/   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/bladelier/standalone-indexer-common_2.12/3.1.5/   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/document-model_2.12/3.1.5/document-model_2.12-3.1.5.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/document-model_2.12/3.1.5/document-model_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/projectA/common/common-io/1.12.48/common-io-1.12.48.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/projectA/common/common-io/1.12.48/common-io-1.12.48.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/hadoop-utils_2.12/3.1.5/hadoop-utils_2.12-3.1.5.pom   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/bladelier/hadoop-utils_2.12/3.1.5/hadoop-utils_2.12-3.1.5.pom.sha1   
Downloading https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/projectA/tokenizer/tokenizer-api/2.6.19-RELEASE/tokenizer-api-2.6.19-RELEASE.pom   
...   
https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/companyXX.sbe.releases-nxrepository/…   
https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/companyXX.sbe.releases-nxrepository/…   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last common / coursierResolutions' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last index-verifier / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last index-comparator / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last generic-tools / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last index-dumper / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last index-analyzer / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last common / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last byname-generator / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output   
[error] (common / coursierResolutions) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 17 error(s) in dependency resolution:   
[error]     com.companyXX.projectA.maven:maven-globalproperties:0.9.30:   
[error]         not found:   
[error]             /Users/userName/.ivy2/local/com.companyXX.projectA.maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/ivys/ivy.xml   
[error]             https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom   
[error]         unauthorized:   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/v3debt/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/central-cache/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/aggregator-nxrepository/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/central/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/thirdparty/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/aggregator-nxrepository/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             http://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/companyXX.sbe.3rdparty-nxrepository/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com/artifactory/companyXX.sbe.releases-nxrepository/com/companyXX/projectA/maven/maven-globalproperties/0.9.30/maven-globalproperties-0.9.30.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]     junit:junit::   
[error]         not found:   
[error]             /Users/userName/.ivy2/local/junit/junit/ivys/ivy.xml   
[error]             https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit//junit-.pom   
[error]         unauthorized:   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/snapshots/junit/junit//junit-.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
[error]             https://artifactory.qa.companyXX.com/artifactory/releases/junit/junit//junit-.pom (Artifactory Realm)   
...
[error] Total time: 246 s (04:06), completed Jul 12, 2023, xx:xx:xx AM
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

Answer (score 1):

After several check, here is what I found helps me solve the issue
**unauthorized:**  in the error log is a key word here, I have 2 different realm in 2 files,
Realm: artifactory.qa.companyXX.com
companyXXcentral.corp.companyXX.com,
the first one password is valid while the second one is out of date, when update the second one, the issue was gone.

But the error message is really confusing for me cause it keeps saying /home/.ivy2/local/xxx/ivy.xml doesn't exists, I thought when sbt version is higher than 1.3.0, it will use Coursier cache instead, and when I resolve the issue I go to /home/.ivy2/local/ folder, those missing files reported in the error log doesn't exits either...